# Mounting VMDK disk image

Tags: mount, computer-forensics, virtual-disk, vmdk

I have a single vmware disk image file with vmdk extension

I am trying to mount this and explore all of the partitions (including hidden ones).

I've tried to follow several guides, such as : http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/469942-mounting-virtual-box-machine-images-host

I'm able to mount the image using vdfuse

```
vdfuse -w -f windows.vmdk /mnt/
```

After this I can see one partition and an entire disk exposed

```
# ll /mnt/
total 41942016
-r-------- 1 te users 21474836480 Feb 28 14:16 EntireDisk
-r-------- 1 te users  1569718272 Feb 28 14:16 Partition1
```

Continuing with the guide I try to mount either EntireDisk or Partition1 using

```
mount -o loop,ro /mnt/Partition1 mnt2/
```

But that gives me the error 'mount: you must specify a filesystem type'

In trying to find the correct type I tried

```
dd if=/mnt/EntireDisk | file -
which outputs a ton of information but of note is:
/dev/stdin: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ....... FATs ....
```

So i tired to mount as a vfat but that gave me

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock ...etc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try ntfs? Did you try `fdisk /mnt/EntireDisk` or `gparted /mnt/EntireDisk`  and looking at the partitions there? Do they show up correctly?

Comment: fdisk returned: 'WARNING: GPT detected on '...'. The util fdisk doesnt support GPT'.  gparted is able to show me there are 4 partitions but all fail to initalize. It lists several required packages for ntfs and fat32 that i might need so I'll install those and see if it gets me anything

Comment: Try installing `ntfs-3g`

Comment: Also, you might want to move this question over to http://serverfault.com/, I bet you would get more help there as this isn't really a software dev or computer science question.

Comment: I saw a lot of solution, but finally I use the simple solution: add the VMDK file to an existed linux VM. Boot to that VM and mount the partition normally. You can use GUI tool to mount (such as gnome-disks in gnome) or `mount` command line

Answer (score 79):

For newer Linux systems, you can use `guestmount` to mount the third partition within a VMDK image:

```
guestmount -a xyz.vmdk -m /dev/sda3 --ro /mnt/vmdk
```

Alternatively, to autodetect and mount an image (less reliable), you can try:

```
guestmount -a xyz.vmdk -i --ro /mnt/vmdk
```

Do note that the flag `--ro` simply mounts the image as read-only; to mount the image as read-write, just replace it with the flag `--rw`.

### Installation

`guestmount` is contained in following packages per distro:

- Ubuntu: `libguestfs-tools`
- OpenSuse: `guestfs-tools`
- CentOS / Fedora: `libguestfs-tools-c`

### Troubleshooting

#### `error: could not create appliance through libvirt`

```
$ guestmount -a file.vmdk -i --ro /mnt/guest
libguestfs: error: could not create appliance through libvirt.

Try running qemu directly without libvirt using this environment variable:
export LIBGUESTFS_BACKEND=direct

Original error from libvirt: Cannot access backing file '/path/to/file.vmdk' of storage file '/tmp/libguestfssF6WKX/overlay1.qcow2' (as uid:107, gid:107): Permission denied [code=38 int1=13]
```

Solution: use `LIBGUESTFS_BACKEND=direct`, as suggested:

```
LIBGUESTFS_BACKEND=direct guestmount -a file.vmdk -i --ro /mnt/guest
```

#### `fusermount: user has no write access to mountpoint`

```
LIBGUESTFS_BACKEND=direct guestmount -a file.vmdk -i --ro /mnt/guest/
fusermount: user has no write access to mountpoint /mnt/guest
libguestfs: error: fuse_mount failed: /mnt/guest/, see error messages above
```

Solution: use `sudo`, or change file permissions on the mountpoint

Comment: That's very helpful. Anyway, I had to use `sudo` and get to the directory as `root` to made this work.

Comment: This worked for me, although the `-m` argument needs a little more explanation. From the [`guestmount` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/guestmount): `Mount the named partition or logical volume on the given mountpoint in the guest (this has nothing to do with mountpoints in the host).`. I found that mounting the first partition with `/dev/sda1` worked, even though the host had it's own `/dev/sda1`

Comment: For debian and proxmox systems it is also the package libguestfs-tools

Comment: I don't understand the `-m` option, but `-i` worked fine. Why is `-m /dev/xxx` needed?

Comment: `sudo guestmount -a abc.vmdk -o "ro" -i --ro /mnt/abc` it only mounts readonly if i use `-o ro`

Comment: The `-m` option is the partition on the vmdk. You can find this with `virt-filesystems -a {path_to_vmdk_file}`.

Answer (score 26):

You can also use qemu:

### For `.vdi` disks

```
sudo modprobe nbd
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd1 ./linux_box/VM/image.vdi
```

if they are not installed, you can install them (issuing this command in Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt install qemu-utils
```

and then mount it with:

```
mount /dev/nbd1p1 /mnt
```

### For `.vmdk` disks

```
sudo modprobe nbd
sudo qemu-nbd -r -c /dev/nbd1 ./linux_box/VM/image.vmdk
```

notice that I use the option `-r`, that's because **VMDK version 3 must be read only** to be able to be mounted by qemu

and then I mount it with

```
mount /dev/nbd1p1 /mnt
```

I use `nbd1`, because `nbd0` sometimes gives: 'mount: special device /dev/nbd0p1 does not exist'

### For `.ova` disks

```
tar -tf image.ova
tar -xvf image.ova
```

The above will extract the `.vmdk` disk and then mount it.

Comment: Additional info about mounting archives and virtual drives: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31669/is-it-possible-to-mount-a-gzip-compressed-dd-image-on-the-fly

Comment: `qemu-nbd: Failed to blk_new_open 'abc.vmdk': Could not open 'abc-s1016.vmdk': Too many open files` it has a total of 1025 files btw, I guess I would have to recompile nbd to let more than 1017 files? the vmdk is split in growing files for a 2TB max size

Answer (score 7):

Install affuse, then mount using it.

```
affuse /path/file.vmdk /mnt/vmdk
```

The raw disk image is now found under `/mnt/vmdk`.
Check its sector size:

```
fdisk -l /mnt/vmdk/file.vmdk.raw

# example

Disk file.vmdk.raw: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000da525

Device       Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/mnt/vmdk/file.vmdk.raw1 *     2048 41943039 41940992  20G 83 Linux
```

Multiply sector size and start sector. In the example it would be 2048*512:

```
echo '2048*512' | bc
1048576
```

Mount the raw file using that offset:

```
mount -o ro,loop,offset=1048576 /mnt/vmdk/file.raw /mnt/vmdisk
```

The disk should now be mounted and readable on `/mnt/vmdisk`.

Comment: No need in manual calculation: just use `offset=$((2048*512))`

Comment: If you have the error: mount: /mnt/vmdisk: cannot mount /dev/loop0 read-only. use the norecovery option: mount -o ro,norecovery,loop,offset=1048576 /mnt/vmdk/file.raw /mnt/vmdisk

Comment: `mount: /mnt/vmdkraw: failed to setup loop device for /mnt/vmdk/MSEdge - Win10-disk001.vmdk.raw`

Its HPFS/NTFS/exFAT, but don't suppose that makes a difference.

Comment: used this however the mounted folder was empty

Comment: ls:`-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1536 Dec 31  1969 abc.vmdk.raw` fdisk:`cannot open abc.vmdk.raw: Permission denied`, any idea?

Comment: For those wondering: `affuse` is part of [afflib](https://github.com/sshock/AFFLIBv3).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer from [commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12554/mount-a-vmware-virtual-disk-.vmdk-file-on-a-linux-box) that worked for me:

```
kpartx -av <image-flat.vmdk>; mount -o /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/vmdk
```

You can also activate LVM volumes in the image by running

```
vgchange -a y
```

and then you can mount the LV inside the image.

To unmount the image, umount the partition/LV, deactivate the VG for the image

```
vgchange -a n <volume_group>
```

then run

```
kpartx -dv <image-flad.vmdk>
```

to remove the partition mappings.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca If you say something does not work, you may also provide details on what exactly did not work.  Like posting an error message or explaining what exactly is wrong.  That would greatly increase value of the comment.

Comment: Sorry!  KPARTX says that the VMDK file format is not recognized.

Comment: This is for ESX's "someimage-flat.vmdk" format, where it works as described.

Comment: `sudo kpartx -av abc.vmdk` gives `llseek error` on ubuntu22.04

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look in [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/quick-tips-mount-vmware-vmdk-file-linux-using-saeed-khodor-mba/) for a download link for VMware Virtual Disk Development Kit (VDDK). Once downloaded and installed:

`vmware-mount -p path_to_vmdk` will show the partitions inside the VMDK file. For example:

```
Nr      Start       Size Type Id Sytem                   
-- ---------- ---------- ---- -- ------------------------
 1       2048  461371392 BIOS 83 Linux
```

Then just do:

`sudo vmware-mount path_to_vmdk 1 /mnt/mount_point`

I tried `guestmount`, but it is very, very slow. Underneath it creates a virtual machine, uses KVM and so on. Crazy stuff, slow as hell.

Comment: Excellent recommendation. IMHO, many people downvoted without giving any rationale. Whereas this is a very high speed method to mount and use vmdk. I copied out 204,803 files in under 9 minutes (even faster than local filesystem copy). @georgiptr You don't need the whole VDDK if you already have vmware player or workstation (and possibly any other vmware product) because vmware-mount is already installed.

Answer (score -3):

Have you got the software package for ntfs?

Try

```
apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

on debian based systems.

Comment: What does the OP's problem have to do with NFS? Did you mean ntfs? An NTFS package would be something like `ntfs-3g`.

Comment: @voidlogic Sorry I've understood your question wrong and SO keeps giving me a prompt of `read-only mode`. Have you try to mount the vmdk file by `vmware-mount`, which can be extracted from the VMware-Workstation.